# ¿Cómo hacer switch php según la variable?

Tags: php

Tengo un sitio multi-idioma, que carga una configuracion de php que es la siguiente:

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'],0,2);

switch($lang){
    case "fr":
        require_once "languages/fr.php";
        break;
    case "it":
        require_once "languages/it.php";
        break;
    case "en":
        require_once "languages/en.php";
        break;
    case "es":
        require_once "languages/es.php";
        break;
    case "ru":
        require_once "languages/ru.php";
        break;
    case "ar":
        require_once "languages/ar.php";
        break;
    default:
        echo "<div class='row justify-content-center'><div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert' id='ioj'><button type='button' class='close' id='clr' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close''>
    <span aria-hidden='true' id='m'>&times;</span></button><strong>Fail!</strong> Language error</div></div>";
    require_once "languages/en.php";
    break;
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer, es en vez de ir poniendo case uno por uno, que a partir de **$lang** que es un valor como es, fr, de, pues eliga un automaticamente el **"languages/$variable.php"**

lo he intentado pero siempre me salia el "**default**"

Comment: @Marcos que segun el variable, si es "es" que elija languages/es.php y asi, con fr o cualquier valor dado, automaticamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución, inspirado en [@Marcos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16597/marcos)

**Empezamos definiendo todos los códigos posibles:**

```
$langs = ["ab","aa","af","ak","sq","am","ar","an","hy","as","av","ae","ay","az","bm","ba","eu","be","bn","bh","bi","bs","br","bg","my","ca","ch","ce","ny","zh","cv","kw","co","cr","hr","cs","da","dv","nl","dz","en","eo","et","ee","fo","fj","fl","fil","fi","fr","ff","gl","ka","de","el","gn","gu","ht","ha","he","hz","hi","ho","hu","ia","id","ie","ga","ig","ik","io","is","it","iu","ja","jv","kl","kn","kr","ks","kk","km","ki","rw","ky","kv","kg","ko","ku","kj","la","lb","lg","li","ln","lo","lt","lu","lv","gv","mk","mg","ms","ml","mt","mi","mr","mh","mn","na","nv","nd","ne","ng","nb","nn","no","ii","nr","oc","oj","cu","om","or","os","pa","pi","fa","pl","ps","pt","qu","rm","rn","ro","ru","sa","sc","sd","se","sm","sg","sr","gd","sn","si","sk","sl","so","st","es","su","sw","ss","sv","ta","te","tg","th","ti","bo","tk","tl","tn","to","tr","ts","tt","tw","ty","ug","uk","ur","uz","ve","vi","vo","wa","cy","wo","fy","xh","yi","yo","za","zu"];
```

Así defino el código por ejemplo "**es**":

```
$cliLang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'],0,2);
```

Luego por si no existe el idioma, cambiamos un **require_once** por un `include_once`:

```
$lang = in_array($cliLang, $langs) ? $cliLang : 'en'; // Inglés por idioma de defecto
$m = "languages/" . $lang . ".php";
```

La **$m** es una variable, para verificar si existe, en instantes será usada.

```
include_once "languages/" . $lang . ".php";
```

Ahora usamos la `$m` y sino existe el idioma requerimos inglés, y mostramos un error:

```
if (!file_exists($m)) {
    echo "<div class='container-fluid'><div class='row'><div class='col-md-10 col-md-offset-1'><div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in center-block' role='alert'><button type='button' class='close' id='clr' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close''>
      <span aria-hidden='true' id='m'>&times;</span></button><strong>Fail!</strong> Language error</div></div></div></div>";
      require_once "languages/en.php";
}
```

Y así sería, si no tienen ninguno de esos idioma (*dificil es...*) pues mostrará un error, pero cargará el idioma inglés, cosa que con `require_once`, no se cargaría y daría error absoluto.

Comment: Considera que la variable `$lang`, siempre tendrá el código a un idioma existente (de lo contrario, no debería estar en el arreglo), por lo que la condición `if (!file_exists($m)) {` carece de sentido.

Comment: @Marcos la función `if (!file_exists($m)) {` si que sirve, si no existe el idioma te muestra el idioma ingles y da error, pero con tu respuesta es lo unico malo que tenía, que requería el idioma por ejemplo `fr.php` y así no podia enseñar el inglés si no existía

Answer (score 3):

Por lo que entiendo, realmente buscas simplificar tu código.

### Solución:

Podrías crear un arreglo con la lista de idiomas que soportas.

#### Ejemplo:

```
$cliLang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'],0,2);
// No incluyo "en" porque es el default
$langs = ['fr', 'it', 'es', 'ru', 'ar'];

// Validamos que idioma este soportado, sino usamos "en"
$lang = in_array($cliLang, $langs) ? $cliLang : 'en';
require_once "languages/" . $lang . ".php";

// Si el idioma del cliente es distinto al obtenido
if ($lang !== $cliLang) {
    echo "<div class='row justify-content-center'><div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert' id='ioj'><button type='button' class='close' id='clr' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close''>
      <span aria-hidden='true' id='m'>&times;</span></button><strong>Fail!</strong> Language error</div></div>";
}
```

Comment: me ha ayudado, gracias, publicaré mi propia respuesta pues he añadido cosas diferentes

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'],0,2);
//Defino los lenguajes en los que tengo configurado mi sitio
$permitidos = ['fr','it','en','es','ru','ar'];
//Si el idioma pasado esta en el arreglo
if(array_search($lang, $permitidos) !== false){
    //Incluyo la configuracion de ese idioma
    require_once "languages/{$lang}.php";
    //Sino muestro un error e incluyo el idioma por defecto (en)
} else {
    echo "<div class='row justify-content-center'><div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert' id='ioj'><button type='button' class='close' id='clr' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close''>
        <span aria-hidden='true' id='m'>&times;</span></button><strong>Fail!</strong> Language error</div></div>";
    require_once "languages/en.php";
}
```